# BeautifulSoup gets nothing between tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I am a novice to write a web crawler. I want to use the searching engine of http://www.creditchina.gov.cn/search_all#keyword=&searchtype=0&templateId=&creditType=&areas=&objectType=2&page=1 to check whether my input is valid.

For example, 912101127157655762 is a valid input, and 912101127157655760 is invalid.

After observing the web source code from developer tools I found that, if the input is a invalid number, the tags would be:
[image]

While if the input is valid, the tags would be:

[image]
So I want to determine whether the input is valid or not by just checking whether there is anything within the 'ul class = "credit-info-results public-results-left item-template"' tag. Here is how I wrote my web crawler:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.creditchina.gov.cn/search_all#keyword=912101127157655762&searchtype=0&
templateId=&creditType=&areas=&objectType=2&page=1'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bs = data.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(bs, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "credit-info-results public-results-left item-template"})
if check == []:
    # TODO
if check != []:
    # TODO
```

However, the value of check is always []. I cannot understand why there is nothing between the tab. Hope somebody may help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got not html but JS object as a response. That's why BS can't parse it.

You can use substring search to check if response contains something or not.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.creditchina.gov.cn/search_all#keyword=912101127157655762&searchtype=0&
templateId=&creditType=&areas=&objectType=2&page=1'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bs = data.read().decode('utf-8')

ul_pos = bs.find('credit-info-results public-results-left item-template')
if ul_pos <> 0:
  bs = bs[ul_pos:]

soup = BeautifulSoup(bs, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "credit-info-results public-results-left item-template"})
if check == []:
    # TODO
if check != []:
    # TODO
```

Comment: How do I know whether I got html but not JS object? Also, I checked that the value of bs.find('credit-info-results public-results-left item-template') is 39202, with both input 912101127157655762 and 912101127157655760, which should have returned different output values. That is confusing...

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try it. Unfortunately, I can't test it by myself since this site banned my requests.

Comment: I found that what I got is just a template of the web. And I need to look at network instead of elements of the developer tools. Thank you anyway for your time and patience!